# Django rest framework : tag serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to display the contents of a deal containing tags (no problem). But I also want to show the list of deals for a specific tag.

deal/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Deal
from . . tag.serializers import TagSerializer

class DealsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='tag_set')

   class Meta:
       model = Deal
       fields = ('url', 'id', 'title', 'link', 'tags')
```

tags/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Tag
from . . . api.deal.serializers import DealsSerializer

class TagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
         model = Tag
         fields = ('url', 'id', 'name')

class TagAllSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    dea_tags = DealsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name', 'dea_tags')
```

deal/models.py

```
tag_set = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='dea_tags')
```

I missed a step because I have an error ImportError: can not import name 'DealsSerializer'

Comment: You have made a cyclic import, hence the error. Python imports files when it goes over an `import` statement, but since your  first file imports the latter and vice versa, there is a problem.

Comment: How can I solve the problem of cyclic import ?